# How to find out, if all specific Keys got a specific Value in an multiarray?

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have a multi Array, and i want to find out (in PHP), if in every subarray the key 'orderOK' is TRUE. If its missing, or FALSE in just one single subarray, the function has to return FALSE.

The Array below is just an example, which cases may occur.

```
Array
(
    [order] => Array
    (
        [cargo] => Array
        (
                [0] => Array
                (
                        [start] => 12345
                        [end] => 23456
                        [length] => 120
                        [orderOK] => TRUE
                )

                [1] => Array
                (
                        [start] => 10234
                        [end] => 07653
                        [length] => 234
                        [orderOK] => FALSE
                )

                [2] => Array
                (
                        [start] => 10234
                        [end] => 07653
                        [length] => 234
                )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Is it about a certain programming language? Did you try anything (e.g. recursion, nested loops), and if so please show your code?

Comment: so main `Array` may have multi `order` and `order` may have multi `cargo` at what level you need `orderOK` to be true? or just for single `cargo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it through a `foreach` loop.  I created a separate function though you could also keep the foreach loop within the same function as your array.

```
<?php 
//assuming $array contains your values

$result = $this->orderok_check($array);  //call your function
if($result){
    //your function returned TRUE   
}else{
    //your function returned FALSE
}

function orderok_check($array) {
    foreach($array['order']['cargo'] as $item){
        if(!isset($item['orderOK']) OR !$item['orderOK']){
            return FALSE;    
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
?>
```